# heroku give error when try to deploy adonis app

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, adonis.js

heroku give error when try to push adonis code

When i am trying to deploy adonis app on heroku some of its database is upload successfully deployed but all the tables are not shown on heroku postgres database.

I have five table in database but on heroku i found only three tables so how can i deploy this successfully.

On locally system this is running successfully.

```
        on run  git push heroku master command

    Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 358 bytes | 358.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.13.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   ~6.13.1
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.13.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.13.1...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm ~6.13.1 (replacing 6.12.1)...
remote:        npm ~6.13.1 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        audited 4233 packages in 4.099s
remote:        
remote:        4 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        audited 4233 packages in 4.391s
remote:        
remote:        4 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 29.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v20
remote:        https://elooopin.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote: 
remote: error: type "undefined" does not exist
remote:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:13)
remote:     at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:403:19)
remote:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:22)
remote:     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
remote:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
remote:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
remote:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
remote:     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
        remote:   name: 'error',
        remote:   length: 97,
        remote:   severity: 'ERROR',
        remote:   code: '42704',
        remote:   detail: undefined,
        remote:   hint: undefined,
        remote:   position: '145',
        remote:   internalPosition: undefined,
        remote:   internalQuery: undefined,
        remote:   where: undefined,
        remote:   schema: undefined,
        remote:   table: undefined,
        remote:   column: undefined,
        remote:   dataType: undefined,
        remote:   constraint: undefined,
        remote:   file: 'parse_type.c',
        remote:   line: '275',
        remote:   routine: 'typenameType'
        remote: }
        remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
        To https://git.heroku.com/elooopin.git
           17d0561..fd3849a  master -> master
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your database configuration. Please [edit] your question and add the relevant part of your config (as *text*, leaving out anything sensitive).

Comment: Can you please share more details about the deployment (process, configuration, ...)?

Comment: I just found my error there is "mediumtext" type of coloum in my database i change it to only "string" and it's work :)

Comment: @ITMAIL Can you please create an answer with your solution (for next viewers)

Comment: yes sure, but i have another problem that adonis app run locally but give error 500 on heroku.

Comment: Can you share heroku logs? And the details of error 500 (if any)

Comment: heroku logs file https://ibb.co/2SbRKcp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204681/discussion-between-crbast-and-it-mail).